# How do I refer to a range in another worksheet in my code?

Tags: excel, range, vba

This works:

```
Sub exemp2()
Dim frange As Range
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Set frange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("A1")
Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(5, 2)).Copy Destination:=frange
Cells(8, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

This gives the 1004 error:

```
Sub exemp1()
Dim frange As Range
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Set frange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range(Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1))
Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(5, 2)).Copy Destination:=frange
Cells(8, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

I can't figure out why I can't refer to the range like in the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the following MSDN explanation on the first parameter `Cell1` (which is marked as *Required*) of `Workseet.Range` property

> The name of the range. This must be an A1-style reference in the
>   language of the macro. It can include the range operator (a colon),
>   the intersection operator (a space), or the union operator (a comma).
>   It can also include dollar signs, but they’re ignored. You can use a
>   local defined name in any part of the range. If you use a name, the
>   name is assumed to be in the language of the macro.

Here you can find **[complete MSDN article on this subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512(v=office.15).aspx)**

### WORKAROUND

However there is another option - you might use the following call:

```
Set frange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range(Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1), _
                                        Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1))
```

instead of

```
Set frange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Range(Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1)
```

This doesn't give any error. Looks like when one wants to use object reference in range cell addressing, the second parameter ought to be given.

Comment: Simpler to only use `Cells`: `Set frange = Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(1, 1)` ;)